# Reuse function call result in angular template

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
<div some-magic="data = getAllData()">
    <div>{{data.foo}}</div>
    <div>{{data.bar}}</div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do, is to prepare all the needed data at once (computation of `foo` and `bar` can be efficiently done togehter.
I've tried to use `ng-init`, but then the `getAllData()` is evaluated only once, while I need something that will be evaluated at every digest cycle.

Is it possible with angular?

Answer (score 1):

Call the function in your controller and store it in a variable on the scope.